# Matplotlib: Is there a way to set default scatter styles with matplotlibrc?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I do a fair amount of plotting with pandas and matplotlib, and I've been looking for a way to help set the default scatter styles in my matplotlibrc file. I do not want to have to edit the matplotlib sourcecode to get default behaviors, because I need to be able to allow coworkers to reproduce work (and want to keep things consistent between machines/VEs, and update without worrying about busting things).

As an example, I want to be able to do:

```
plt.scatter(
    df["dep_var"],
    df["ind_var"],
    alpha=0.5,
    facecolors="none",
    edgecolors="#444444",
    linewidth=2,
)
```

With:

```
plt.scatter(
    df["dep_var"],
    df["ind_var"],
)
```

With overwritten alpha, face colors, edge colors, and linewidth in the matplotlibrc file (or some other non-source code location). But when I add

```
scatter.alpha : 0.5
```

to my matplotlibrc file, I get a Bad Key warning.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: The only relevant key I see would be `"scatter.edgecolors"`. A custom style isn't an option?

Answer (score 0):

I think that a possible solution is use the RC parameter like:

```
plt.rcParams["scatter.edgecolors"] = "#444444"
plt.rcParams["lines.linewidth"]=2
```

You can check more about ket for Rc [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#customizing-with-matplotlibrc-files)

You only need to run this once! If you restart the kernel it will be reverted to the default.